# Access workflow ExectionProperties from Activity

Tags: workflow-foundation-4

When I derive an activity from NativeActivity, I can access Workflow executionproperties using the NativeActivityContext like this:

`context.Properties.Find("propertyname");`

Some of my activities derive from Activity, because I they define a coded workflow using the Implementation property. An Activity has an ActivityContext, which does not provide access to the workflow execution properties, it does not have a Properties property.

Is there another way to get access to the workflow execution properties from within an Activity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would seem not. Using Reflector you can see that the ExecutionProperties class is only exposed in two places. One is the `NativeExecutionContext.Properties` and the other is related to the WCF/WF4 interop bits in the `IReceiveMessageCallback.OnReceiveMessage()`.